# Problem: nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64

Tags: opensuse, rpm, dependencies, zypper

I'm trying to install downloaded `percona` RPM packages:

```
> ls -1
Percona-Server-5.7.10-3-r63dafaf-el7-x86_64-bundle.tar
Percona-Server-57-debuginfo-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-devel-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-test-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Percona-Server-tokudb-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

By running the following command:

```
> sudo zypper in Percona-Server-*.rpm
```

But I receive this error:

```
Problem: nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
 Solution 2: break Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or skip, retry or cancel [1/2/s/r/c] (c):
```

I wonder what command I need to run to automatically install all RPM packages and all their dependencies? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically zypper does just that; installs and resolves RPM dependencies as long as it has the necessary RPM's in its list of repositories much like the YUM toolkit.

In this case the [percona howto](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/installation/yum_repo.html) shows you how to add their RPM repository to the YUM list of repositories.

zypper is not so different; the following should work

```
$> wget http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-4/percona-release-0.1-4.noarch.rpm
$> rpm -ivh percona-*.rpm
```

That should create a new .repo file at /etc/zypp/repos.d/ which will allow you to account for depencies (unless you don't have any support repositories defined, in which case you would want to install the latest OpenSSL RPM to address the libcrypto.so dependency)